# Cannot cast to type though type

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I get the following exception when I want to cast one type to another.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.paston.certification.data.impl.BRL6000 
cannot be cast to org.paston.certification.data.Certification
```

BRL6000 extends the Certification. So in my understanding I should be able to cast a object of the type BRL6000 to the Certification type.

This is the code where the exception occurs.

```
Object certification = ch.getCertificationData(process, version);
Certification c = (Certification)certification;
```

**Deploying**

The application is deployed from Eclipse to a Tomcat 7 server. My application uses a few JARs from the Tomcat environment (e.g. Bonita_Server.jar).

My application is (in Eclipse) a dynamic web projects which references an other project (Certificationnl) which contains the classes `Certification` and `BRL6000`. Project Certificationnl is added to the webproject's WAR when I deploy the application to Tomcat.

**Classes**

The BRL6000 class

```
package org.paston.certification.data.impl;

import org.paston.certification.data.Certification;
import org.paston.certification.data.CertificationStep;

public class BRL6000 extends Certification{

    /**
     * 
     */
    public static final long serialVersionUID = -8215555386637513536L;
    public static final String processName = "BRL6000";

}
```

Certification class

```
package org.paston.certification.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.ow2.bonita.facade.runtime.impl.AttachmentInstanceImpl;

public class Certification implements java.io.Serializable{

    public enum Section{
        ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN
    }
    /**
     * SerializationVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5158236308772958478L;


}
```

getCertificationData

```
public Object getCertificationData(String process, String version) {
    if (loginContext == null)
        login();

    System.out.println("Process: "+ process + " Version: "+ version);
    ProcessDefinitionUUID pdu = new ProcessDefinitionUUID(process, version);

    QueryRuntimeAPI queryRuntimeAPI = AccessorUtil
            .getQueryRuntimeAPI();

    try {
        Set<ProcessInstance> processInstances = queryRuntimeAPI
                .getProcessInstances(pdu);

        if (processInstances.size() != 1)
            System.out.println("Best number of instances is 1. Found: "
                    + processInstances.size());

        for (ProcessInstance processInstance : processInstances) {
            Map<String, Object> variables = processInstance
                    .getLastKnownVariableValues();
            if (((Boolean) variables.get("active")) == true) {              
                return variables.get("certification");
            }
        }
    } catch (ProcessNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Update with code as a Servlet**

```
package org.paston.certification.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.paston.certification.CertificationHandler;
import org.paston.certification.data.Certification;
import org.paston.certification.data.CertificationI;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SomeServlet
 */
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SomeServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        CertificationHandler ch = new CertificationHandler();
        String process = request.getParameter("p");
        String version = request.getParameter("v");
        Object certification = ch.getCertificationData(process, version);
        Class<?> clazz = certification.getClass();
        while (clazz != null) {
            System.out.println(clazz.getName());
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        }

        Class c1 = certification.getClass().getSuperclass();
        Class c2 = Certification.class;

        System.out.println("c1 is " + c1 + ", c2 is " + c2);
        System.out.println("c1 == c2 is " + (c1 == c2));
        System.out.println("c1.equals(c2) is " + c1.equals(c2));
        System.out.println("c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()) is "
                + c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()));
        System.out.println("c1.getClassLoader() == c2.getClassLoader() is "
                + (c1.getClassLoader() == c2.getClassLoader()));

        CertificationI c = (CertificationI) certification;

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Console output of the Servlet:

> Process: BRL6000 Version: 1.0
>   org.paston.certification.data.impl.BRL6000
>   org.paston.certification.data.Certification java.lang.Object c1 is
>   class org.paston.certification.data.Certification, c2 is class
>   org.paston.certification.data.Certification c1 == c2 is false
>   c1.equals(c2) is false c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()) is true
>   c1.getClassLoader() == c2.getClassLoader() is false

There is also one other issue that maybe hinting for the problem. Every 10 seconds I see the following Exception in the console:

```
May 07, 2013 2:09:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.ow2.bonita.runtime.tx.StandardTransaction.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.ow2.bonita.util.ReflectUtil.loadClass(ReflectUtil.java:68)
    at org.ow2.bonita.env.descriptor.ObjectDescriptor.construct(ObjectDescriptor.java:195)
    at org.ow2.bonita.env.WireContext.construct(WireContext.java:521)
    at org.ow2.bonita.env.WireContext.create(WireContext.java:498)
    at org.ow2.bonita.env.WireContext.create(WireContext.java:484)
    at org.ow2.bonita.env.WireContext.get(WireContext.java:456)
    at org.ow2.bonita.env.WireContext.get(WireContext.java:343)
    at org.ow2.bonita.env.WireContext.get(WireContext.java:746)
    at org.ow2.bonita.env.BasicEnvironment.get(BasicEnvironment.java:151)
    at org.ow2.bonita.env.BasicEnvironment.get(BasicEnvironment.java:142)
    at org.ow2.bonita.util.EnvTool.getEnvClass(EnvTool.java:175)
    at org.ow2.bonita.util.EnvTool.getTransaction(EnvTool.java:84)
    at org.ow2.bonita.runtime.tx.StandardTransactionInterceptor.execute(StandardTransactionInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.ow2.bonita.services.impl.EnvironmentInterceptor.execute(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.ow2.bonita.services.impl.RetryInterceptor.execute(RetryInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.ow2.bonita.runtime.event.EventExecutorThread.run(EventExecutorThread.java:61)
```

**Update 2**

I came to understand the problem a little better. The Bonitaserver ( `AccessorUtil` ) **does** load the Certification object as well. It somewhere loads the classes from `Certification.jar1620768823629427276.tmp` which the Bonitaserver created when a process was uploaded to the server.

Also, I found a class `ReflectUtil` ([link](http://www.bonitasoft.org/docs/javadoc/bpm_engine/5.10/org/ow2/bonita/util/ReflectUtil.html)) which is probably used to load those classes.

What I tried is to load the classes at the start of the doGet for both this (the servlet) as the `ClassLoader` of the `AccessorUtil`. Both with the same old result.

```
    ArrayList<String> classesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    classesNames.add("org.paston.certification.data.Certification");
    classesNames.add("org.paston.certification.data.CertificationI");
    classesNames.add("org.paston.certification.data.impl.BRL6000");
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    Class<?>[] classes =  ReflectUtil.loadClasses(cl, classesNames);
```

**Update 3**

Results of the following code proposed by @GaborSch. The code as I used it:

```
    System.out.println("--- Test ClassLoader certification object---");
    ClassLoader cl1 = certification.getClass().getSuperclass().getClassLoader();
    while (cl1 != null) {
        System.out.println(cl1.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " " + cl1.hashCode() + " " + cl1);
        cl1 = cl1.getParent();
    }
    System.out.println("--- Test ClassLoader Certification class---");
    ClassLoader cl2 = Certification.class.getClassLoader();
    while (cl2 != null) {
        System.out.println(cl2.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " " + cl2.hashCode() + " " + cl2);
        cl2 = cl2.getParent();
    }
```

Result of the code:

```
--- Test ClassLoader certification object---

org.ow2.bonita.runtime.ProcessClassLoader 451656
org.ow2.bonita.runtime.ProcessClassLoader@6e448
org.ow2.bonita.runtime.VirtualCommonClassloader 1182018350
org.ow2.bonita.runtime.VirtualCommonClassloader@46742b2e
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader 318536939
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@12fc7ceb
sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader 1667514408
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63644028
sun.misc.Launcher.ExtClassLoader 1253061906
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@4ab03512

--- Test ClassLoader Certification class--- 

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 2136824254
WebappClassLoader   context: /Certification   delegate: false  
repositories:
    /WEB-INF/classes/
----------> Parent Classloader: org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@12fc7ceb

org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader 318536939
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@12fc7ceb
sun.misc.Launcher.AppClassLoader 1667514408
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@63644028
sun.misc.Launcher.ExtClassLoader 1253061906
sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@4ab03512
```

Comment: Please show definitions of your classes `BRL6000` and `Certification` and code that causes the exception.

Comment: are you sure you're inheriting from / casting to the right type of certification? You could have imported another Certification type by accident.

Comment: It baffles me how people expect help without posting the broken code.

Comment: If you're absolutely positive that it extends the right superclass/interface, then this problem can also happen when you're running a Java environment utilizing multiple classloaders (e.g. Java EE web application) and the classpath is cluttered with multiple copies of the same superclass/interface at different places (e.g. one copy in webapp itself, another copy in server itself or maybe the EAR or even the JRE/lib). A class/type which is loaded by classloader X does namely not equal the very same class/type which is loaded by classloader Y.

Comment: @AlexR you are right. I added the code

Comment: Could you also provide the `getCertificationData()` method signature and body?

Comment: What package is BRL6000 in?

Comment: And which Certification class does it import?

Comment: @vlad-ardelean yes, also tried to use `org.paston.certification.data.Certification` instead of `Certification`just to be sure.

Comment: @sp00m added `getCertificationData()`

Comment: @xagyg `org.paston.certification.data.impl`

Comment: @JBNizet `org.paston.certification.data`

Comment: lets see the import and package section of BRL6000 ..

Comment: @Kal added the import/package section

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen It seems to be a classloading problem then. Are you sure that your calling class and the `Certification` definition are loaded by the same classloader? What's the deployment structure? Isn't your `jar` put twice on on the path of two different classloaders?

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen what happens if you change the return type to `public Certification getCertificationData(...)` ? Do the explicit casting in that method.

Comment: @GaborSch `Certification.jar` is in a Tomcat server (/lib). My code is launched from Eclipse maybe there is a hint for the trouble? Though other classes used from Tomcat wont give any problems.

Comment: Try to print the classes out to confirm its a classloader issue. `Class<?> clazz = certification.getClass();while (clazz != null) { System.out.println(clazz.getName()); clazz = clazz.getSuperClass();}`

Comment: @GaborSch the orginal return type of `getCertificationData` was `Certification` and casted the `variables.get("certification")`(return type: Object) to `Certification` instead. That is where i first encounted the issue.

Comment: @Kal your code returns: 
`org.paston.certification.data.impl.BRL6000
org.paston.certification.data.Certification
java.lang.Object`
Looking good well, at least as expected.

Comment: @BalusC cleaned up some references... redeployed and the same issue persists. I'm now at least sure that the JAR with BRL6000 and Certification is only available once.

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen Did you set that public serialVersionUID to private in BRL6000 (or remove the serialVersionUIDs from both classes altogether?). Just trying to strip it back to basics.

Comment: @xagyg i removed both serials.

Comment: Very likely you have two different class loaders.  Classic symptom.  (And this can happen without multiple copies of the class in the classpath.)  Simplest fix is to add a dummy reference to your BRL6000 class in `main`, so it gets resolved early, in the default loader.

Comment: Well, if the same "issue" persists, then you still have multiple copies of that class in the runtime classpath. Exceptions are not being thrown for pure decoration or to tease specifically you. Perhaps you're just not fully aware/understanding what the classpath covers?

Comment: @HotLicks: I'm not sure how your comment makes sense. You're implying that having multiple classloaders is a problem at its own. This is absolutely not true.

Comment: @BalusC - Certainly having multiple classloaders is not in itself a problem.  But having the same class loaded by two different classloaders is.  Even if they come from the same .class file they are regarded as two distinct classes.

Comment: @Hot: Okay. It's probably that I just don't see what you're adding up to what's already been commented before.

Comment: @BalusC - Your comment implies that there *must* be two different copies of the class for this problem to occur.  This is definitely not true (though it is often the case).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the root of the problem lies in the runtime environment.

Your `Certification` data ultimately come from `AccessorUtil.getQueryRuntimeAPI()`, which is a static method run by Tomcat, so all object instances coming from it are likely to be loaded by the Tomcat classloader.

If you copy the jar file under Tomcat, it will load it with its own classloader. Your eclipse-run code although uses a different classloader, and if they have no common ancestor classloader where this `Certification` class is loaded, they will be **considered as a different Class**.

I suggest to review your runtime class paths, remove libs from you Tomcat, or (worst case) run your code within Tomcat (e.g. as a Servlet in the same app).

**Update:**

Based on the project deployment description I believe that

- The `AccessorUtil` class is loaded by a common class loader
- The lists inside are populated by `Certification` instances from your `Certificationnl` classes *from your Tomcat deployment*
- You can access those objects through the `AccessorUtil` class, but the class definitions are not accessible from your Eclipse code.

It's a bad idea to access Tomcat-defined objects from outside on JVM-level. Either put your code into the same container, or use a properly-defined interface (e.g. web services).

If you want to stay with the current project setup, you could also use interfaces that are put into the common classloader (next to `AccessorUtil`), and cast to the interface.

**Update 2:**

To check the class loader hierarchy, execute a code like this:

```
Class c1 = certification.getClass().getSuperclass().getClassLoader();
while (c1 != null) {
    System.out.println(c1.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " " + c1.hashCode() + " " + c1);
    c1 = c1.getParent();
}

Class c2 = Certification.class.getClassLoader();
while (c2 != null) {
    System.out.println(c2.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " " + c2.hashCode() + " " + c2);
    c2 = c2.getParent();
}
```

You can find the common ancestor by comparing the stack. The best way to go on is still *debugging*.

**Update 3:**

It is visible that your common classloader is `org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader`. On top of that

- `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader` is present for your webapp (this is where you want to **cast to**)
- `org.ow2.bonita.runtime.VirtualCommonClassloader` and `org.ow2.bonita.runtime.ProcessClassLoader` are present where the objects come from (that's **where they're instantiated**)

It seems that *Bonita* is using some kind of classloading mechanism.

The solution is that you make the `StandardClassloader` (or any other classloader) to load your classes. Since `Certification` (and thus `BRL6000`) are dependent to Bonita classes, you must put `Bonita_Server.jar` into *endorsed*. See the [Tomcat Classloader HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html), it may give you more insight.

**Update 4:**

To do the serializing/deserializing recommended in my comments, you can use this piece of code:

```
Certification certification = null;
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(ch.getCertificationData(process, version));
    oos.flush();
    certification = (Certification) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())).readObject();
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
}
```

Note that the `(Certification)` cast is made to the currently loaded class.

**Update 5:**

The final resolution was **not using direct Java class-level access**, but rather using a proper API to do the same trick.

Comment: Arg! I removed the jar from Tomcat and added it to the deployment assembly of my web project.. guess what? The same exception persists.

Comment: So, what is your runtime environment *exactly*? You could add it to your question, 'cause I think that's relevant.

Comment: added a description to my the orignal question.

Comment: Check `tomcat/lib`, `YOR_WEBAPP/lib` and probably global `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: @GaborSch I'm unsure whether I understand your comment about interfaces correctly. I created a `CertificitionI` interface implemented in the `Certification` and put the whole JAR in the `Tomcat/lib`. That is what I understood from that remark. (For me it is the first time I encounter such an issue so still trying to really understand it)

Comment: From this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html i also understand that if both `AccessorUtil` as `CertificationI`/`Certification` should now be loaded by the common class loader since they are both in the `/lib` directory. Thus the code from @stephenc should return true at the classloader compare. Instead it returns false.

Comment: OK, I see that the classloaders are different. But why don't you put your code inside the tomcat? Create a `Servlet` or a `ServletFilter` is simple, and you can run it by calling a URL. That's the simplest solution for your problem.

Comment: Well, the code is already available from a URL and is already deployed into Tomcat. I also tested with a servlet (added code in the original question). The results are still the same.

Comment: That's strange. Try debugging your code, find out *where* those instances are created and *what classloaders* are used there. You can also set a **ClassLoader breakpoint** in Eclipse (I recommend to use a condition for  the classname).

Comment: Any progress in this issue?

Comment: @GaborSch yes, I found out that there is the Certification is loaded twice see Update 2 under in the original question.

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen Updated my answer. I'd be happy if you could post the result to your question.

Comment: @GaborSch I have updated the question with the code as I used it and the results.

Comment: @GaborSch could moving the JAR influence the workings of the original webapp? I know get a `500` on both the original Bonitasoft app as on on my application. `java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.ow2.bonita.env.BonitaEnvironmentParser.getDocumentBuilderFactory(BonitaEnvironmentParser.java:104)`

Comment: @GaborSch The line in Bonita where things go wrong has something todo with `ClassLoaders` as well `final URL url = BonitaEnvironmentParser.class.getClassLoader().getResource("bonita-environment.xsd");` Could this have anything todo with the jar being in the `endorsed` directory?

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen Now I started to read something about Bonita. It's a complex software, where the internal representation can change without prior notice. I really don't recommend to build on that. Rather use some EJB or REST API, they're safe. If you really want to do something, [serialize/deserialize](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-serialization/) your instances. If you're using the same class definitions, it will work.

Comment: @GaborSch thanks anyway! At least learned a lot about ClassLoaders ;-) I'm now switching to the REST api which seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two possible explanations:

- You have managed to load the `Certification` class in two different classloaders.
- You have two `Certification` classes that have names that just *look* the same.

Here's what I suggest you do to figure out what is going on.

- Before the statement that does `(Certification) certification` insert the following:

  ```
  // Get the classes that are being compared in the typecast.
  Class c1 = certification.getClass().getSuperclass();
  Class c2 = Certification.class;

  System.out.println("c1 is " + c1 + ", c2 is " + c2);
  System.out.println("c1 == c2 is " + c1 == c2);
  System.out.println("c1.equals(c2) is " + c1 == c1.equals(c2));
  System.out.println("c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()) is " + 
                     c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()));
  System.out.println("c1.getClassLoader() == c2.getClassLoader() is " +
                     c1.getClassLoader() == c2.getClassLoader());
  ```
- Check that the first line gives (what looks to be) the same names for `c1` and `c2`.  (If not, we've selected the wrong classes to compare.  Tweak my code to get the right ones.)
- The `c1 == c2` and `c2.equals(c2)` tests should give the same answer, and I predict it will be `false`.
- Comparing the names is the tests that distinguishes the two alternative explanations:

  - If the names are equal, it is indicative of a classloader problem.
  - If the names are not equal, then you have two different classes whose names look the same but actually aren't.  (How can that be?  Well Java uses Unicode, and some of the European charactersets use the same "glyph" for different characters.  Depending on the fonts you are using, you get pairs of characters that *look* the same when you view them in an editor / IDE, but in fact aren't.
- The final test will confirm that `c1` and `c2` do or do not have the same classloader.

---

This won't explain *why* your web application is in this state, but it will clearly tell you whether the problem is classloaders, funky class names ... or something else.

Comment: +1 I'm sure there are a few odd scenarios that doesn't cover, but it's a good step in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. this at least gives me some extra insights. The classloaders are not the same. c1 == c2 returns false aswell.